# Generating a List in M Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to generate a list using M Query, but instead of generating a list starting from a specific, number, I want the number to start at 1 and then add 1 for every row on another table.

So for example, if I have:

```
Tbl1 

Col1
A
B
C
D
D
```

I want to generate

```
Tbl2
Col1
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Hi JaCrispy, have you got anything in progress that's not working?

Comment: Your example outcome looks like a table with 1 column rather than a list. So what do you want: a list or a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the number to start at 1 and then add 1 for every row on another table.

if I understand your correctly, here it is:

```
={1..Table.RowCount(Tab1)}
```